# Relay candidates are not generated in Google Chrome

Tags: webrtc, stun, turn, rfc5766turnserver

For testing if I am getting the relay candidates, I am using this page: http://googlechrome.github.io/webrtc/samples/web/content/peerconnection/trickle-ice/. To test from chrome 40, I provided my turn url and credentials there. After clicking gather candidates I can see no relay candidates. Doing the same test from firefox 36, I found the relay candidates. What could be the possible problem ? To further investigate the issue, I looked into wireshark log. What I found is, from firefox the stun request format includes-

```
STUN 146 Allocate Request UDP lifetime: 3600 user: lazy realm:  with nonce
```

But from chrome, this is slightly different-

```
STUN 70 Allocate Request UDP
```

It seems the request code is not same. Moreover, request from chrome doesn't include the lifetime, user and realm property.

Answer (score 1):

I know the question is already a bit old, however from my experience the TURN server description format (with regards to authentication) has to be formatted differently in Chrome and Firefox.

For chrome you can use:{"url": "turn:user@turn.example.com", credential:"password"},

For Firefox the format is:
{"url": "turn:turn.example.com", 'hasCredentials': true, username:"user", credential:"password"},

Maybe you can check the source to see how the turn servers are set in the example.

Edit:
Meanwhilst the format of the servers list has changed in the specification (https://www.w3.org/TR/webrtc/#rtciceserver-dictionary). Currently all implementations i know support the format:

```
{ "urls": ["turns:turn.example.org", "turn:turn.example.net"],
   "username": "user",
   "credential": "myPassword",
   "credentialType": "password"
}
```

On Edge however it seems you need to include the query string ?transport=udp in the url.

Answer (score 0):

This question is nice years old at this point but I believe it is the same problem I've been seeing just now. I was testing a web application on an android mobile device and had what I think is the same issue: although I was setting a turn server in the web-side config, when I would start the connection it would not connect and looking in chrome://webrtc-internals I could see that the relay never appeared at all as an ice candidate. I captured the traffic on the host-side and I could see that although the server was sending a challenge the client was never trying to authenticate. I tried many different things and finally figured out what the issue was (and I was unable to turn up anything after many google searches). I had left the realm empty in my server config. I didn't think this would be an issue but it seems the android implementation just won't try to send the credentials at all if the realm is empty. Once I set it to a non-empty string, the browser sent the credentials and it worked fine. I can see in your question above that you probably had the realm empty as well since the message was formatted with

> STUN 146 Allocate Request UDP lifetime: 3600 user: lazy realm:  with nonce

So... as it's been nine years I guess you solved your issue somehow or abandoned this but I bet this would've fixed it.

I would add that disappointingly there were *no* indications in the chrome webrtc internals diagnostic page indicating why it ignored/discareded the turn relay, it just just silently did so. Logged an [issue](https://issues.chromium.org/u/1/issues/329978076) in the Chrome tracker, maybe it'll get some traction.